# After share website on server, only mainpage works

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a website and when I share it on trial server everything was ok. After I bought the domain so I must upload everything files again. Problem is that routung doesn't work correctly. I see only main page and whe I try open other page I see error 404. Chmod I change to 777 (public_html and folder with other files). 
For example:

```
//This works
Route::get('/', [
            'uses' => 'FrontendController@rules',
            'as' => 'en.rules'
        ]);
//This doesn't work
Route::get('/rules', [
            'uses' => 'FrontendController@rules',
            'as' => 'en.rules'
        ]);
```

I found this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-only-home-page-route-working-on-live-server but it doesn't work too. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have published the providers and tag files if using third-party modules.

> php artisan vendor:publish

Comment: have you published all the providers and tag files?